# How to import and use Jinja macros in a python script (Saltstack setup)

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I have a **saltstack setup** where one of my pillar file is written in python. This pillar file is pulling some data from a json file. In this python script, there are 2 functions. In the second function, I want to import and use one of the existing salt macros. The structure of this pillar file is something like this

mypillar.sls

```
#!py
import json

def somefunc{
some code here which is pulling data from a json file
}


def secondfunc{
  This is where I want to use the macro
}
```

If this would have been an sls file, I know it can be imported like

```
{% from 'my/code/struct/macros1.sls' import getMacro %}
```

And I've used this macro in few of my other sls files using the above command. It works flawlessly there. However, I'm not sure if this can be used in **mypillar.sls** file which is actually a python script.

I tried the below commands to import:

- {% from 'my/code/struct/macros1.sls' import getMacro %}
- {{ from 'my/code/struct/macros1.sls' import getMacro }}
- from my.code.struct.macros1.sls import getMacro - This is python style but it couldn't find "my" directory only so stuck

So all I want is this macro to be reused in python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Jinja macros are Jinja code, and cannot be run in Python without setting up a full Jinja context and providing a template.

If you want to share code between Python and Jinja in Salt, then [write a custom python module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/) that they can then both use.

```py
# salt://_module/macros.py

def some_function():
  ...
```

```py
#!py

def secondfunc{
  val = __salt__["macros.some_function"]()
  ...
}
```

```
#!jinja|yaml

key: {{ salt["macros.some_function"]() }}
```

Note also that pillar is designed for distributing secrets to minions. If you have a lot of complex template logic here building non-secret data then you should consider moving it out to the state tree for improved performance.